# Why access the attributes of a Python class by reference?

Tags: object-oriented, python, class-design, attributes

### Attribute references and instantiation

In [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), that is part of the official Python documentation, I have found the following information:

> **Class objects** support two kinds of operations: **attribute references** and **instantiation**.
>
> *Attribute references* use the standard syntax used for all attribute references in Python. So if `MyClass` is the name of a class and `func` is the name of one attribute of `MyClass` then:
> `MyClass.func` is a valid attribute reference.
>
> *Class instantiation* uses function notation. So `x = MyClass()` creates a new instance of the class and assigns this object to the local variable `x`.

At the beginning of previous documentation the expression `Class object` is used and this means that in Python *a class is an object* and
on this *object* we can execute only 2 operations and one of these is *attribute references*.

Up to now I have used the *Attribute references* only in one case to access a method of a class: for writing a unit-test which verified the exact sequence of method calls.

I show a simplified code of the test below (for details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448113/testing-python-methods-call-sequence-in-a-multithreaded-context/74472438#74472438)):

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class A:
    def __f1(self):
       pass
    def __f2(self):
       pass
    def __f3(self):
       pass
    def method_1(self):
       self.__f1()
       self.__f2()
       self.__f3()

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call_order(self):
        mock_a = mock.create_autospec(A)
        expected = [mock.call._A__f1(),
                    mock.call._A__f2(),
                    mock.call._A__f3()]
        # call method_1 by reference
        A.method_1(mock_a)
        self.assertEqual(expected, mock_a.mock_calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I generally **create an instance of a class** and invoke the methods of the class by this instance object.
*On my opinion it's better to use a python module which contains functions and global variables than create a class and access its attributes by reference.*

### My question

When or why can it be useful to access the attributes of a class by *Attribute references* and without an instance of that class? What is the point of this language feature? I have a hard time to imagine a case where attribute references make sense without an instance.

*An example  where it is absolutely necessary the use of such an attribute reference (as in my example) will be appreciated.*

Comment: Have you any experience with `static` members in C++ / C# / Java?

Comment: I have used static methods in Java but I think that an abusing of them is not very compatible with OOP. In Python all methods are accessible by reference. So on my opinion this the same to use a module which contains functions instead a class.

Comment: Dear community-hardliners, before downvoting on this question, think twice why you did not give any hints to the OP here on [meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/how-to-improve-my-question). Just downvoting a question with no comment where the OP explicitly asked for help is extremely unsocial behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That reference isn't describing a special case of the language rules, it's a natural result of *everything* being an object.

The special case is that `MyClass(args...)` is wired up to create a new object and call `MyClass.__init__` (among other things).

It allows you to change the state of the class after it is defined. This can be as simple as changing "static" data based on some configuration.

```
class EggsApiClient:
    default_url = "example.com"
    def connect(self):
        # do stuff with default_url

if __name__ = "main":
    EggsApiClient.default_url = parse_args("default_url")
```

Comment: Thanks. Please change `default_url: "example.com"` to `default_url = "example.com"` in your answer. Very interesting yuor sentence **it's a natural result of everything being an object**.

Comment: When I start to program with Python I think I abused in the use of objects and classes because I was coming from OOP in Java language. Now I think that in many cases I have to use a module and put inside global variables (instead attributes of a class) and functions (methods of a class). I'm convincing that to use modules, functions, global variables is more pythonic than use attribute reference.

Comment: Very interesting your example `MyClass.__init__` is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much you help me to better understand the hidden Python logic.

Comment: I'm not sure this really addresses the question.  Also, you can do similar things with class level variables in, e.g., Java even though classes are not objects.

Comment: @JimmyJames my point is there's a simplicity in Python's design here. Rather than having separate language features for each case, everything is an object, so everything can be read and written

Comment: @Caleth I agree with that, but it doesn't really speak to *why* you would use the class attributes.

Comment: `MyClass(...)` isn't even that much of a special case. Classes are first-class objects in Python, instances of `type`. `type.__call__` defines what it means to call a given type, which typically involves creating an object with the class's `__new__` method (most commonly inherited from `object`), then passing the new object to the class's `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3):

This is not something that I think most Python users will ever need to do **and almost surely shouldn't** but it does have a distinct purpose and it's worth understanding.

Consider the following example:

```
class Foo:
    def set_a(self, a):
        self.a = a

class Bar:
    def set_b(self, b):
        self.b = b

foo = Foo()

foo.set_a(1)

print(foo.a)

bar = Bar()

# interesting part here!
Foo.set_a(bar, 2)

print(bar.a)
```

Through this feature, we have effectively called `set_a` on a `Bar` instance, despite the fact that `Bar` doesn't have a `set_a` method defined. That is, if we try:

```
bar.set_a()
```

We get an error: `AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'set_a'.`

You might (quite reasonably) ask, "OK, but why would I do that?"  Personally, I think I did something like this many moons ago but there was probably a simpler solution to whatever I was trying to accomplish.

I can imagine this be useful in various frameworks e.g. something like unit testing.  But the main reason I think you might end up doing this is when you are using a more functional style.  For example, you might have a function like this which has no knowledge of Foo or Bar:

```
def apply(obj, func, *params):
    func(obj, *params)
```

Which you can then call like so:

```
apply(bar, Bar.set_b, 3)

print(bar.b)
```

A real example of the kind of thing you might actually do:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, student: bool):
        self.name = name
        self.student = student

    def is_student(self):
        return self.student
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - student: {self.student}"
    
people = [Person("bob", False), Person("alice", True), Person("carl", True)]

def display(iter):
    print("---")
    for i in iter:
        print(i)


display(people)

display(filter(Person.is_student, people))
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
people = map(Person, ["dave", "edith", "frank"], [True, False, True])

display(people)
```

Check out the [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) module for more interesting functional-style approaches like this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer with the anwser of Caleth have added much to my my poor knowledge of Python. I agree with you that the use of attribute reference is inside framework or other special cases.

Comment: My real difficult concern on the fact that sometimes I have to avoid to create class in Python and use module because classes are not so needed as for example in Java.

Comment: @frankfalse I consider this to be intermediate to advanced Python knowledge.  The fact that you are even asking suggests you may be underestimating yourself. My opinion is that with Python, you *should* use module level code as long as it meets your needs and isn't becoming spaghetti code and only introduce classes when they provide a clear benefit.

Comment: I agree with you and in the future I will use this approach to programming with the Python language. The code write in the past will remain as it is, but I think the use of Python class will decrease in my next new programs.

Comment: The fact that you *can* do this in no way suggest you *should*. As to why it's *possible* requires an understanding of the descriptor protocol in Python and how it implements `foo.set_a(1)` as `Foo.set_a(foo, 1)` (via an intermediate call to `Foo.set_a.__get__(foo, Foo)`).

Comment: @chepner I'm pretty sure I did not suggest anyone *should* do this.  Doing things like this is like cave diving.  Not for amateurs.

Comment: @JimmyJames You may not have suggested it, but I'm sure someone will try to do it anyway :) My comment is directed towards them.

Comment: @chepner I added a strong warning to the first sentence.  Better?

Comment: @chepner I assume you are talking about calling one classes method but with an object of a different class.  The functional-style examples are fine, right?